# Volumetric Mesh Cutting Algorithms For Simulating Sculpture

Tags: mesh

I am interested in whether there an available algorithms to give me insights on how to cut a volumetric mesh?

Comment: I think you need to say more about specifically what you want to do. The question as is is just too unspecific.

Comment: How can I cause damage to volumetric mesh, I want to simulate material damage or crack?

Comment: I still don't know what "cause damage to volumetric mesh" means. Assuming you want to cut or remove cells, what *specifically* you're struggling with? Finding software? Finding algorithms? Finding data structures?

Comment: I want to simulate the dental surgical tool for cutting a soft tissue. I am using SOFA Framework carving plugin, however, it is only remove surfaces not cutting the volumetric mesh. I am looking for an algorithm for cutting the this volumetric mesh, the algorithms at sofa is only for removing surface which not useful for my case to see the mechanical performance of the mesh..

Comment: I have to admit that I have no idea what SOFA actually is. What have you tried so far? Have you done a literature search?